# Compare two datatables and draw those that differ into new DataTable efficiently

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

In essence I have two datatables

DataTable 1

```
PirateShipID  PirateShipPreference
123            1
122            2
121            3
```

And DataTable 2 (which has different named columns, but the data types are the same.

```
RGPirateShipID PirateShipPreferenceType
123             1
122             1
121             3
```

I want to grab all records where

```
PirateShipID == RGPirateShipID && PirateShipePreference != PirateShipPreferenceType
```

Ideally using Linq as I believe that would be my quickest way of accomplishing this

```
        var idsNotinPirates = from r in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                          //Get all records that don't match on preference
                          where DataTable2.AsEnumerable().Any(r2 => r["PirateShiptID"] == r2["RGPirateShipID"] && r["PirateShipPreference"] != r2["PirateShipPreferenceType"])
                          select r;
```

However, DataTable 1 has about 10k pirateships and Datatable2 has 1 million.

It takes the application a long time to complete the above.

How can i make this more efficient?

Comment: Have you tried joining the tables instead of doing an `Any`?

Comment: Exploring join in Linq...  is it possible to have it equal one propery and not equal the other property?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should probably be doing something like this:

```
var query = from r in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
            join r2 in DataTable2.AsEnumerable() on r["PirateShipID"] equals r2["RGPirateShipID"] into joinedTable
            where joinedTable["PirateShipPreference"] != joinedTable["PirateShipPreferenceType"]
            select r
```

Comment: That sounds like a fantastic idea, but the join into joinedtable makes thejoin an IEnumerable <DataRow> object which can't be put in the where like pictured.  I'm thinking it should be 


`select joinedtable.where(joinedtable.PirateShipPreference != joinedTable.PirateShipPreferenceType"`

though in lambda and slightly different.. but I can't figure it out just yet.